# Prove an infinite set A is countable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In one of my classes I was asked to prove the following theorem.

Given a set $A$, which is a infinite set, another set $B$, which is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

If there exists a function/map $f$ s.t. $f: B\to A$, the function $f$ is onto. Then the set $A$ is countable.

Our definition of countable is that a set $X$ is countable if and only if it is numerically equivalent to any subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Our definition of numerical equivalence is that the set $X$ is numerically equivalent to the set $Y$ if there exists a map $g$ s.t. $g: X\to Y$, which is one-one(injective) and onto(surjective).

Here is my proof:

Consider any element $a$ from $A$. Since $f$ is onto, then there exists a set of inverse image of $a$, call this set $F(a)$.

1. If $F(a)$ has only one element, then we proceed to the another element from $A$, and consider its inverse image.
2. If $F(a)$ has more than one elements, then take the least element from $F(a)$, then processed to another element from $A$.

Iterating this process for all the elements of $A$. We have a set $F(A)$ which is the set of all the inverse image of $A$ satisfying the above conditions.

Define a map $F: A\to F(A)$, then $F$ is both one-one and onto. Thus $A$ is numerically equivalence to $F(A)$ which is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Thus the set $A$ is countable.

Is my proof rigorous? If not, can anyone kindly show me how to do this rigorously?

Our professor also mentions we can prove this through Axiom of Choice, but I have no idea how to do that since this is a real-analysis course, and we are not required to do it.

Comment: @JMoravitz The least element he is picking is from $B$. Since $B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$, every subset of $B$ will have a least element.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Fair enough, I read poorly.

Comment: @JMoravitz's comment about your proof requiring the Axiom of Choice is still correct.  Being able to select elements of $A$ and select preimages requires the Axiom of Choice in the event they are infinite.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 I am fully aware of that but our professor only give us a very simple definition, and did not focus on that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardinality is measured by bijections.Since set A is infinite,and we have a surjection from set B to set A,then set B has to have at least as much elements as A(greater than or equal cardinality).Namely $|A| \leq |B|$

Now a fact is that least infinite cardinal is $\aleph_0$ and it is cardinality of natural numbers.

Now we use a fact that any infinite subset of natural numbers is countable to conclude following:
$$|\mathbb N|=\aleph_0=|B|$$

Also for any infinite set $X$ it holds that $\aleph_0 \leq |X|$

From equation :
$$\aleph_0 \leq |A| \leq |B| = \aleph_0 $$ thus by Bernstein-Schroder theorem we conclude that set A is countable.

If you want justification of any of above results,please leave a comment.They are pretty basic results about infinities

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, however, I have not yet learned any of the materials you mentioned . The professor wants us finish this before he discusses cardinality.

Comment: If you want you could grab Jechs Introduction to set theory,or Endertons Elements of set theory,also I would be willing to expand the answer if needed.

Comment: It seems to me that the main point of the problem is to prove a special case of the fact that you state without proof in your first paragraph: namely, if there is a surjection from $B$ to $A$, then $|A| \le |B|$, meaning that there is a bijection from $A$ to a subset of $B$.  To prove this in general, one needs the Axiom of Choice (or some fragment thereof) but in the present case it is not necessary because $\mathbb{N}$ is wellordered (a fact that the OP is using when talking about "least elements".)  The rest of your answer does not seem very relevant; Bernstein-Schroder is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is mostly okay.  There are only a few changes that I would make:

1. You should not define things called $F(a)$ and $F(A)$ prior to defining a function called $F$.
2. You say "define a function $F$..." but you do not actually define a function.  I would guess that you mean to define $F(a)$ as the least element of $f^{-1}(\{a\})$, but perhaps you got confused because you had already defined something called $F(a)$ (see point 1.)
3. You refer to "iterating this process", which suggests that you are defining a function by recursion.  But this is not really what you are doing.  You can say where any given element $a \in A$ should map to without regard for any "previous step".